# Gvim - Relative line numbers bug (Graphics rendering bug)

Tags: vim, gvim

I'm not sure if there is a bug in the rendering code of Gvim or whether there is something in my `.vimrc` / `.gvimrc` which has caused a rendering problem.

[image: gvim rendering bug]

As can be seen on the above image, there is a pink-ish line next to some of the line numbers.

Here is the contents of my vimrc:

```
colorscheme elflord
syntax enable
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
set expandtab
set number
set showcmd
set cursorline
filetype indent on
set showmatch
set incsearch
set hlsearch
set autoindent
set nocompatible
set tags=tags;
set ruler
set path+=**
set wildmenu
set number relativenumber
augroup numbertoggle
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufEnter,FocusGained,InsertLeave * set relativenumber
    autocmd BufLeave,FocusLost,InsertEnter * set norelativenumber
augroup END
```

Here is the contents of my gvimrc:

```
set guifont=Monospace\ 8
set guioptions -=T

" Blueshift color scheme
" by Jan Zwiener, mail: jan@zwiener.org
" Based upon the pyte color scheme by Henning Hasemann
"
" 2010/11/16: Version 1.0
"

set background=light

hi clear
if exists("syntax_on")
  syntax reset
endif

let colors_name = "blueshift"

" Taglist colors
hi MyTagListFileName    guifg=black   guibg=#c0d0e0
hi MyTagListTagName     guifg=black   guibg=#ffbc29

if version >= 700
  hi CursorLine     guibg=#f6f6f6
  hi CursorColumn   guibg=#c0d0e0 "#f6f6f6
  hi MatchParen     guifg=black     guibg=#dfdfdf

  hi TabLine        guifg=black     guibg=#b0b8c0
  hi TabLineFill    guifg=#9098a0
  hi TabLineSel     guifg=black     guibg=#f0f0f0 gui=bold

  hi Pmenu          guifg=white     guibg=#808080
  hi PmenuSel       guifg=black     guibg=#ffbc29
endif

hi Title        guifg=#202020   gui=none
hi Underlined   guifg=#202020   gui=underline

hi Normal       guifg=black     guibg=white
hi ModeMsg      guifg=black     guibg=white
highlight Cursor       guifg=#f0f0f0   guibg=#101010
highlight LineNr    guifg=#ffffff    guibg=steelblue

" new for newer versions of vim/gvim
highlight CursorLineNr gui=bold guifg=DarkRed guibg=#c0d0e0

hi Visual       guifg=white     guibg=#5381bc
hi WildMenu     guifg=black     guibg=#ffbc29
hi IncSearch    guibg=black     guifg=#ffbc29
hi Question     guifg=black     guibg=#ffbc29

hi StatusLine   guifg=white     guibg=#8090a0 gui=bold
hi StatusLineNC guifg=#708090   guibg=#ced5db gui=none
hi VertSplit    guifg=#a0b0c0   guibg=#a0b0c0 gui=none

hi NonText      guifg=#bebebe   guibg=#f2f2f2
hi Comment      guifg=#008000   gui=italic
hi Folded       guifg=#708090   guibg=#c0d0e0
hi Folded       guifg=#708090   guibg=#c0d0e0
hi FoldColumn   guifg=#708090   guibg=#c0d0e0

hi Constant     guifg=black
hi Number       guifg=black
hi Float        guifg=black
hi Boolean      guifg=#0048ff
hi String       guifg=#4070a0   gui=none

hi Statement    guifg=#0048ff   gui=none
hi Type         guifg=#0048ff   gui=none
hi Structure    guifg=#0048ff   gui=none
hi Identifier   guifg=#0048ff   gui=none
hi Function     guifg=#0048ff   gui=none
hi Repeat       guifg=#0048ff   gui=bold
hi Conditional  guifg=#0048ff   gui=bold
hi Operator     guifg=black

hi PreProc      guifg=#1060a0   gui=none
hi Define       guifg=#1060a0   gui=bold
hi Include      guifg=#1060a0   gui=none

hi Error        guifg=red       guibg=white     gui=bold,underline
hi Todo         guifg=white     guibg=#1060a0   gui=bold
hi SpecialKey   guifg=#1060a0   guibg=white
hi Special      guifg=black     guibg=white

" Diff
hi DiffChange   guifg=NONE      guibg=#e0e0e0   gui=bold
hi DiffText     guifg=NONE      guibg=#f0c8c8   gui=bold
hi DiffAdd      guifg=NONE      guibg=#c0e0d0   gui=bold
hi DiffDelete   guifg=NONE      guibg=#f0e0b0   gui=bold
```

Comment: Have you copied the blueshift color scheme into your `.gvimrc`? Better put it in `~/.vim/colors/`, and enable it via `:colorscheme blueshift`.

Comment: I don't think this is the right place for such a problem. There's a dedicated [Vim StackExchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/), but I don't think it belongs there, neither. Please report this bug to the Vim developers, see `:help bugs`. Basically, open an issue at the [bug tracker](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues), or directly discuss this on the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php). Please include the GVIM `:version`, and operating system specifics, too.

Comment: @IngoKarkat Are you able to reproduce this?

Comment: No, using GVIM 8.0.1358 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a bug in your `.vimrc`.

On Windows I use GVIM without any extra configuration. The coloring, relative numbering, and absolute numbering works perfectly